# Sitefinity search results - no Page Descriptions

Tags: sitefinity

Anybody have any idea why Sitefinity's search index, or rather search results page, is not showing a description for pages found? It does for News and Blog items, but not for pages.

We've already got content for the description of the page (in the page properties)

We've now re-indexed, made sure the pages have descriptions and keywords, restarted IIS, deleted and recreated the search index, nothing's happening. We still only get an elipsis for the description of pages when searching

Regards,
Jacques

Answer (score 0):

what version of sitefinity are you using? have you tried modifying the fieldsinfoprovider.xml file in the search folder? see this article for more details: http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/kb/sitefinity-3-x/how-to-customize-the-indexing-of-html-documents.aspx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <fields>
      <field name="title" weight="1" indexAttribute="" filterTag="title" filterAttributes="" />
      <field name="keywords" weight="1" indexAttribute="content" filterTag="meta" filterAttributes="name:keywords;" />
      <field name="description" weight="1" indexAttribute="content" filterTag="meta" filterAttributes="name:description;" />
      <field name="script" weight="-1" indexAttribute="" filterTag="script" filterAttributes="" />
      <field name="style" weight="-1" indexAttribute="" filterTag="style" filterAttributes="" />
    </fields>
```

make sure that it is set to index the description meta tag...

hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, seems I already have that setting in the fieldsInfoProvider.xml file: 
  <field name="description" weight="1" indexAttribute="content" filterTag="meta" filterAttributes="name:description;" />

Everything seems to be 'indexed' just fine including the description tags, but the problem we're having is that in the Search Results page News and Blog items show a paragraph between the title and the hyperlink, but Page results don't. Any ideas?

Comment: Incidentally, the version is 3.7 SP4